# How can I prevent content from overlapping when I resize my browser?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning web development through The Odin Project and I'm currently stuck on the landing page project. I feel like everything looks the way it should from the template I'm using, but I notice there is overlap with the 'Placeholder' image at the top (the pug) and with the 'Sign Up' button at the very bottom. I've done a lot of research and I've tried changing the display settings to 'block', 'inline-block' and flex.

This is also my first project working from scratch, so I know my HTML and CSS is very messy. Please be kind :) I've been working on this for over a week now and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong! I suspect that it might have something to do with my negative margins, but I'm not sure.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it? It would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my HTML and CSS: https://codepen.io/palmercury/pen/eYExONy

```css
#wrapper{
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}

body{
    display:flex;
    min-height:100vh;
}

.pics {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 52px;
    margin-bottom:32px;
    margin-top:32px;
  }
  
  .info {
    max-width: 100px;
  }

  .text{
      text-align: center;
      display:flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      

  }

.header, .links, .footer, h1{
    background-color:#1f2937;
    color:#f9faf8;
    padding:16px;
    
}

.header{
    padding:16px;
    margin:auto;
}

.quote{
    font-size: 36px;
    background-color: #E5E7EB;
    color: #1f2937;
    font-style:italic;
    padding:100px;
    font-weight:200;
}
.call-to{
    background-color:#3882f6;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:12px;
    margin:80px;
    padding:32px;
    gap:16px;
    display:block;
}

.call{
    display:flex;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-right:300px;
    border:solid #ffffff;

}
.signup{
    margin-left:40px;
    text-align: left;
    
}

h1{
    color:#f9faf8;
    font-size:48px;
    font-weight: 900;
    display:flex;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left:150px;
}

h3{
    padding-left:40px;

}

.subtext{
    background-color: #1f2937;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin:auto; 
    padding-left:150px;
}

button{
    margin:150px;
    background-color: #1f2937;
}

button{
    background-color:#3882f6;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius: 9px;
    margin-top:16px;
    margin-bottom:16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.main-content{
    display:block;
    
}

.links{
    font-size:18px;
    color: #e5e7eb;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right:50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.placeholder{
    margin-top:-250px;
    padding-right:150px;
    padding-top: -200px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background-color:#1f2937;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-end;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    display:flex;
    gap:8px;
    margin-right:50px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-top:-80px;
    
}

.random{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    text-align: center;
}


a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ffffff;

}



.footer{
    text-align: center;
    padding:32px;
}

#wrapper{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylish.css">

</head>


<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h3>Header Logo</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
     <h1>This website is <br> awesome.</h1>
     <p class="subtext">This website has some subtext that goes here under the <br> main title. It's a smaller font and the color is lower contrast.</p>
    </div>

    <button>Sign-Up</button>
    </div>

    <div class="placeholder">
        <img src="https://c8.alamy.com/comp/2AT0FHN/cute-pug-dog-walking-in-park-2AT0FHN.jpg" width="400" alt="a pug puggin'">
    </div>
    
    <div class="middle-content">
        <p class="random">Some Random Info</p>
    </div>


    <div class="pics">
        <div class="info">
          <img src="images/images.png" alt = "Catfe Lounge">
          <div class="text">This is some subtext under an illustration or image.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <img src="images/images.png" alt = "Catfe Lounge">
            <div class="text">This is some subtext under an illustration or image.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <img src="images/images.png" alt = "Catfe Lounge">
            <div class="text">This is some subtext under an illustration or image.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <img src="images/images.png" alt = "Catfe Lounge">
            <div class="text">This is some subtext under an illustration or image.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="quote">
        <h2>This is an inspiring quote,
or a testimonial from a customer. Maybe it's just filling up space, or maybe will actually read it. Who knows? All I know is that it looks nice.</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="call-to">
       <h3>Call to Action! It's time!</h3>
        <p class="signup">Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</p>
       <button class="call">Sign Up</button>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        Copyright - Palmmercury 2021<BR>
            Photo Credits: <a href="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcatfelounge.com%2Fcat-adoption%2F&psig=AOvVaw2i5EK8KpqPOlzrUQPvhGEf&ust=1636500695396000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAkQjhxqFwoTCIDmnKr2ifQCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD">Catfe Lounge</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you referring to the look of the signup button at the bottom and the pug image overlapping everything else when you resize your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the left text and the image in a single container (wrapper), and apply display:flex;

Remove the margin and the paddings from the placeholder image.

You should do something like:

```
 <div class="hero">
    <div class="text-button-area">
    Left content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="image-area">
    <img>Image goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

You can then apply a display:flex to the hero container. Read more about Flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you so much! I am actually learning Flexbox now, and I feel like I understand how it works, just not how to put it together from scratch. I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Try looking into this: https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-flexbox-grids/

Your code is a bit messy, so I would try to redo, based on the article above. Flexbox is very easy to use, once you understand its key concepts. You can then specify rules for making it responsive, based on the screen size, using @media queries.

Also, if you want to learn flexbox in an easy interactive way, try this: https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: I looked at that, thank you. I've also played the Flexbox Froggy game a few times. I know my code is super messy! I think I have way more classes and divs than I actually need. I think I will try to redo this project from scratch. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score -1):

One way is to set a `min-width` value to the `body`, like so:

```css
body{
    display:flex;
    min-height:100vh;
    
    min-width: 1200px;
}
```